# web service security at different level

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

I am just getting started with SOAP web services and stumbled across web service security.

I needed to know 2 things based on following use case:-

Suppose, there is web service which accepts country name as request and returns state list as response.

what is transport level security and message  level security based on my above simple use case. How they are different?

Comment: depends on what you implement

Comment: does this mean if transport security is implemented then to open wsdl file in browser i have to give username password

Answer (score 2):

> what is transport level security and message level security based on my above simple use case. How they are different?

There are multiple options how to secure your transport channel and data. It all depends what security measures are required.

SOAP/WSDL has an extension [WS-Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) which defines multiple standard options how to secure the communication.  Please note that not all frameworks support all options and I really sugest you use some mature webservice framework (CXF, Axis2, ..)  which would implement the web-service security. You don't want to do it yourself.

**Transport level security**

The basic is TLS/SSL (simple or with client certificate). This security layer is bound to the HTTP tranport layer and often assumed as granted, so not configured in the WSDL itself.

> does this mean if transport security is implemented then to open wsdl file in browser i have to give username password

I assume you are talking about HTTP basic authentication. It is one of the options (and IMHO the poor one and it is strongly bound to the HTTP transport layer)

You can as well use UsernameToken option. It looks similar as basic authentication - there's username and password (or digest) in the SOAP header, as advantage I consider that this extension can be defined and enforced as part of the WSDL or security policy definition.

**message level security**

Under this level we consider signing and/or encrypting the messages.

Comment: so, what I have understood so far, if transport levels security is implemented then there is a username+password or security cert. Sender and receiver both have to have those username+password or security cert to access the carried msg. Actually, any one who has the credentials and url can work with the underlying web service. And in the case of message level security underlying messages are encrypted . Am I right in understanding? and can both security be implemented same time?

Comment: I think for the most part you have it correct @ofortuna but things can be separate, you can have just username and password based auth in which case yes, the user credentials could be shared, or you can have TLS security which can be more difficult to compromise as it uses private , public keys and certificates or you can combine them and use TLS with user/pass.  It also looks like based on what gusto2 said that you could combine all three kind of like a russian doll ;-)  Keep in mind when adding encryption there will be overhead on server and client